# Создание новой формы из task

Tags: многопоточность, javafx, task

Здравствуйте. Имеется метод по созданию новой формы и поток, по завершении которого хотелось бы эту форму создать.

Метод:

```
public void showGameForm() {
    try {
        System.out.println("1");
        FXMLLoader gameLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view/game/GameForm.fxml"));
        System.out.println("2");
        SplitPane gameForm = (SplitPane) gameLoader.load();

        // Создаём диалоговое окно Stage.
        System.out.println("3");
        Stage gameStage = new Stage();
        System.out.println("4");
        gameStage.setTitle("HumanGo");
        //gameStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        System.out.println("5");
        gameStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        gameStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        System.out.println("6");
        Scene scene = new Scene(gameForm);
        System.out.println("7");
        gameStage.setScene(scene);

        // Отображаем диалоговое окно и ждём, пока пользователь его не закроет
        //gameStage.showAndWait();
        System.out.println("8");
        gameStage.show();
        System.out.println("gameStage:" + gameStage.toString());
        System.out.println("loader:" + gameLoader.toString());
        System.out.println("scene:" + scene.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Поток, по выполнении которого должен открыться новый фрейм (`mainApp.showGameForm();`):

```
public Task taskObject = new Task<String>() {
    @Override public String call() {
        while (true) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                updateMessage("Cancelled");
                break;
            }
            progressIndicator.setOpacity(indicatorOpacity);
            requestUserSession.setUserSession(parameters,null);
            responseUserSession = ObjectRequestSender.sendGetRequest(LOG_URL, requestUserSession);
            System.out.println("Имя пользователя: "+responseUserSession.getUserName()+"\tId пользователя: "+responseUserSession.getUserId(responseUserSession.getUserName()));
            updateMessage("Имя пользователя: "+responseUserSession.getUserName()+"\tId пользователя: "+responseUserSession.getUserId(responseUserSession.getUserName()));
            if (responseUserSession.getAuth() == "AUTH") {
                if (indicatorOpacity >= 0) {
                    indicatorOpacity -= 0.35;
                } else {
                    indicatorOpacity = 0;
                    cancel();
                    mainApp.showGameForm();
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    updateMessage("Cancelled");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return parameters;
    }
};
```

Программа зависает на строке метода showGameForm() `Stage gameStage = new Stage();`
Если я вызываю метод showGameForm() из любого друго места кроме потока, то всё работает нормально. Все остальные команды потока работают нормально.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто-нибудь подскажет в чём моя ошибка.
Думал, что ошибка может быть в том, что taskObject имеет тип String. Пытался сделать её Void - не помогло.
Как я понимаю, поток, выполняющийся на текущем фрейме каким-то образом не дает создасться новой сцене. Я понимаю, что решение не идеальное, готов выслушать любую критику или совет.

Comment: Предполагаю, что вызывать метод нужно принудительно в `FX` потоке( `Platform.runLater()` ). Возможно стоит сесть слушателем на статус потока и вызывать внутри него. Если нужно, могу завтра расписать подробней.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю, Andrey M. Всё заработало с использованием `Platform.runLater()`.
Выкладываю свой исправленный код taskObject:

```
public Task taskObject = new Task<String>() {
    @Override public String call() {
        while (true) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                updateMessage("Cancelled");
                break;
            }
            progressIndicator.setOpacity(indicatorOpacity);
            requestUserSession.setUserSession(parameters,null);
            responseUserSession = ObjectRequestSender.sendGetRequest(LOG_URL, requestUserSession);
            System.out.println("Имя пользователя: "+responseUserSession.getUserName()+"\tId пользователя: "+responseUserSession.getUserId(responseUserSession.getUserName()));
            updateMessage("Имя пользователя: "+responseUserSession.getUserName()+"\tId пользователя: "+responseUserSession.getUserId(responseUserSession.getUserName()));
            if (responseUserSession.getAuth() == "AUTH") {
                if (indicatorOpacity >= 0) {
                    indicatorOpacity -= 0.35;
                } else {
                    indicatorOpacity = 0;
                    cancel();
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() {
                            mainApp.showGameForm();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    updateMessage("Cancelled");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return parameters;
    }
};
```